# The server was not found or was not accessible.Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, ssms

I am trying to learn MVC by building a basic Asp.net MVC web application which has a `Sample.mdf`file(Sample Database) in the `Instances-->v11.0` folder. Sql Server **2012** localdb is installed on my Windows 10. I'm **able** to access,create databases and tables(Employee) using server name **(localdb)\V11.0** in SQL Server Management Studio **2017** and also from **command prompt**. I'm using **Windows authentication** and using **local IIS** as a web server however when I try to access the same through C# code(VS 2015) I'm getting following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details

In the line: `con.Open();`

Employee Controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Employee
    public  ActionResult Index()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBACESS"].ConnectionString;

        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Id,Name,City from Employee", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]);
                    employee.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                    employee.Gender = rdr["Gender"].ToString();
                    employee.City = rdr["City"].ToString();

                    employees.Add(employee);
                }
            }
        }
            return View(employees);
    }
}
```

**URL**:

> localhost/WebApp/Employee

**Connection String**:

```
<add name="DBACESS" connectionString="server=(localdb)\v11.0;database=Sample.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

While debugging I found that before executing `con.open()` ServerVersion property of con object is not set and showing error:

> 'ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'”?

**Employee Model Class:**

```
`public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }`
```

**Authentication Mode:**

```
`<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>`
```

I have tried various fixes from stack overflow and forums but nothing worked.

1)Tried other instances like **mssqllocaldb** or **v12.0** but no success.

2)Changed **identity type** to **Local System** from ApplicationPoolIdentity in **IIS** but no success(infact tried all possible scenarios)

3)Set **Load User Profile** to **True** in **Advanced Settings** of **DefaultAppPool** in **IIS**,but no success.

4)Set `setProfileEnvironment="true"` in **applicationHost.config** (but no success.)

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

5)There are no items in **SQL Server Services** in **Sql Server Configuration Manager**.
  It doesn't sound weird cause I found below information for localdb:

> LocalDB doesn't create any database services; LocalDB processes are started and stopped automatically when needed. The application is just connecting to "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0" and LocalDB process is started as a child process of the application. A few minutes after the last connection to this process is closed the process shuts down.

6)**Port no 1433** is **enabled** for **TCP/IP** in **Client Protocols** tab in **Sql Server Configuration Manager**.Moreover I already had created my own Inbound rules for allowing access to port no 1433 for TCP/IP and program for dynamic ports as well in **Windows Firewall**.But no success.

7)In **SSMS**-->Right Click on **Server**--->**properties**-->**Connections** tab I have ticked **Allow remote connections to this server** but no success.

8)Here is my usermapping for the login. **db_owner** and **public** enabled for this user. [User Mappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK3vy.png)

9)**Server Roles** are **public and sysadmin** for my login user.

10)In **SSMS**-->Right Click on **Server**--->**properties**-->**Security** tab I have enabled **SQL server and windows authentication mode** too but no success.

11)Reinstalled SQL server localdb but no joy.

12)I'm attaching the Windows event log file for detailed error.[Windows event log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1abjnv449ucgvi6/sql%20server%20stackoverflow%20Event%20log.txt?dl=0)

I'm beginner to ASP.net MVC. Quick Help will be highly appreciated.Trying since last three days but no joy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that is proper use of `database` attribute in the connection string. I think you want `Initial Catalog`, and drop the ".mdf", so it is just `sample`.

Comment: Tried using Initial Catalog also but no success.

Comment: Change the app pool to run under your user account to see if it works but don't make that the permanent fix.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that?I don't have any idea.

Comment: Change connection string as Crowcoder suggest.  Check your instance of the connection using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with sql server.  The login window contains the instance of the connection,  Make sure you are using same instance that is in login window.  The login an using the explorer check under databases that you are using the correct database.

Comment: Just like you changed Identity Type to Local System, this time select Built-In Account and use your windows login.

Comment: @jdweng The instance name in the login window is **v11.0**.  
The same is used in my connection string. In the left side explorer in SSMS I can see **Sample** database.

Comment: @Crowcoder In Built in Account I can only see **LocalService** ,**NetworkService**,**ApplicationPoolIdentity** but where is my Windows login?

Comment: Sorry, I meant custom account, not built-in. I don't have IIS installed for reference on the machine I'm using at the moment.

Comment: @Crowcoder I tried with my windows username and password but after restarting the service I'm getting **HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.**

Comment: @Crowcoder Actually with my Custom Account, as soon as I start the DefaultApppool in IIS it gets stopped within 2 seconds.Why??That might be the cause of 503.

Comment: @jdweng Here is the snapshot of my SSMS.
[SSMS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ur8wrm7nvgnjv8c/SSMS.PNG?dl=0)
Everything working well with SSMS and cmd Prompt but not with code.

Comment: Use following connectionstring : connectionString="server=.\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=True;"  If this doesn't work then use (localdb) instead of period.

Comment: I would create a console app with your connection string and make sure that works. Then work on your IIS setup issues.

Comment: @jdweng No success with this connection string.Getting error **The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)** in chrome browser and SSMS.
Can you please see the Windows event log file link posted in question above.

Comment: use cmd.exe type >set.  See what localdb is set to.

Comment: @jdweng I typed **sqllocaldb >set** in cmd and nothing happened.

Comment: just  : SET  ;      will will display all the environmental variables.

Comment: Their **isn't** any localdb in the list of env variables.

Comment: You said you can connect with SSMS, so your problem is not that the instance is not created, but you can confirm by running a developer command prompt and doing `sqllocaldb info`

Comment: @Crowcoder Confirmed..Instance is created and running well. Output of `sqllocaldb info` is `mssqllocaldb
v11.0`.

Comment: Well there you go. The instance name is not just `v11.0`, it is `mssqllocaldb v11.0`, though it is odd to have a space in the name.

Comment: @Crowcoder Actually there are two instances one is **v11.0** and another is **mssqllocaldb** I just copied and pasted from cmd that's why there is space :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying almost everything,**nothing** worked.
Atlast I **uninstalled** localdb 2012 and **installed SQL server express 2012**.It worked like a charm!!But I don't know what was the real issue in localdb:(.
Now I am using entity framework and connection string(generated by **ADO .net Entity Data Model**) is:

```
<add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EmployeeDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EmployeeDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EmployeeDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local)\MYDEVEXPRESS12;initial catalog=Sample;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use standard SQL security instead of Windows Integrated - it's easier to do. Set up a new login in SQL server and a new user that uses that login to the database you're trying to access (make the user an 'owner' of the database). Then use this connection string, replacing username and password with the credentials for the login you've set up:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

The issue is nothing to do with your code, it's purely an authentication issue with SQL server and will almost certainly be related to what SQL server is receiving as authentication credentials. The fact you're getting the message shows your code is working and trying to connect, and failing at the final stage of authenticating. Using a SQL server login makes it clearer what authentication you're passing, and will help to eliminate the cause of the issue.

Comment: I tried using sql server Authentication but didn't worked.Generated the connection string by creating ADO .net Data Model which came: `<add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EmployeeDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.EmployeeDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.EmployeeDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\V11.0;Initial Catalog=Sample;User Id=myuserId;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`.I tested the connection and it was tested OK.What's wrong?

Comment: Btw I'm using entity framework.Can you please look at point 5 above i.e Why there are no items in SQL Server Services in Sql Server Configuration Manager.Here is my [SSCM](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zue4pg42oreh7tr/SSCM.PNG?dl=0)